# Find and replace a string in a file with sed efficiently

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I have a sublime text config file, and I want to change the proxy settings for package control when I move between college and home. The file has the following structure:

```
{
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "AdvancedNewFile",
        "jQuery Snippets pack",
        "Nettuts+ Fetch",
        "Package Control",
        "Theme - Aqua",
        "Theme - Soda"
    ],
    "http_proxy": "ProxyA:port",
    "https_proxy": "ProxyA:port"
}
```

Now, I need to replace the `http_proxy` variables with 3 values. It can either be *ProxyA* or  *ProxyB* or *""* for no proxy. I want to be able to do this efficiently using `sed`. Now suppose I want to set the proxy to *ProxyB*. Then I would check if the proxy is either empty or set to  *ProxyA* and then do a find and replace. So there can be 3 cases:

1. When the proxy is to be set to *""* , we need to do a replace for *ProxyA*, *ProxyB*
2. When the proxy is to be set to *ProxyA* , we need to do a replace for *""*, *ProxyB*
3. When the proxy is to be set to *ProxyB* , we need to do a replace for *""*, *ProxyA*

I could do this using two sed commands. What is the most efficient way of achieving this? I think it can be done with a single sed command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in other words, it doesn't matter *which* of those three values is present.

```
sed -r 's/"http(s?)_proxy": "(Proxy[AB])?"/"http\1_proxy": "ProxyA"/' inputfile
```

will replace any of the three possible values with `ProxyA`. (Of course that means it will also replace `ProxyA` with itself, but that's the compromise you need to make if you want to fit it all into a single regex.)

Comment: I hope I got the command line syntax right. I have never used sed.

Comment: @Annihilator8080: Ah, I think I know why. I had overlooked the `:port`  part of the original string. Is that part always there, and is it always this exact string `":port"`? If not, what exactly is it?

Comment: Ok. There was some syntax error, but your solution works. Only problem is here I can not take care of both the `http` and the `https` variables. Can I take care of both the variables in one command?

Comment: @Annihilator8080: A `?` makes the previous token optional, so `https?` matches both. I've edited my answer. By adding parentheses around the optional `s`, a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) is created, allowing me to reference that part of the match using `\1` in the replacement part of the expression.

Comment: Works like a charm @Tim. Do you mind explaining me how does the `\1` switch match with only a part of the string and not the entire match?

Comment: @Annihilator8080: `\1` contains the text matched by the first pair of parentheses in a regex, `\2` contains the text matched by the second pair, etc. There's a link in my previous comment that explains this in detail.